# Why is type undeclared?

Tags: swift, xcode7

I have a very simple example that I can't get to work. Both classes are in the same iOS project. I get this error when I build:

> Use of undeclared type 'classB'

It happens in classA on the `static var` line.

```
import UIKit

class classB: NSObject {
    var temp:Int?
}

import UIKit

class classA: NSObject {
    static var classBList:[classB]?
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting any error for this. I just tried the exact code and it didn't show any error. Tried putting them in the same file and also in different files, both cases worked. If they are in separate files can you check that both files are included in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you might get this error is if the ClassB file is not included in the project. If classA and classB are in separate files then verify that classB is included in the project. The reason why you are getting this error is because the compiler is not finding the class definition of classB. This can happen if the file is not included in the target.

Comment: Thanks. Checking that fixed it. I also had an associated watch app. classA was shared across both. classB was not part of the watch app. Once I added classB to the watch app (through file inspector), it compiled. It's weird that the error pointed to the iOS instead of the watch app though.